# Finding Max in CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is producing the data below. So far so good. I need to find the max(list_price) of the cte. Should I consider all the code below as a new "cte2" and find the max of that? I tried using "max(BK.list_price)" in the outer query but then I can't figure the Group By. (Using SQLS 2008 R2)

```
with cte as
(
  select BT.book_id
  from
    bkinfo.book_topics BT
  where
    BT.topic_id = 'DB'    
)
select BK.book_id, BK.list_price
from bkinfo.books BK
where BK.book_id in
(
  select cte.book_id
  from cte
)
;
go

book_id                              list_price
----------- ---------------------------------------
1105                                   59.95
1108                                   39.95
1109                                   80.00
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: Do you need only the max price as the returned result, or you need to show the book id associated with it as well?

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need CTE for that:

```
select MAX(BK.list_price)
from bkinfo.books BK
where exists
(
    select BT.book_id
    from bkinfo.book_topics BT
    where BT.topic_id = 'DB'
    and BT.book_id = BK.book_id
)
```

Comment: Szymon: That returns the same data as above. I need the max price for the table as a whole. This will be a scalar result, I believe.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to carry both the `book_id` and its price, where the price is at the highest in the topic. This might be overkill, but in general you might want to find the `Nth` most expensive book per topic:

```
with cteBookCostsPerTopic as
(
  select 
     BT.book_id, BK.list_price, BT.topic_id,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BT.topic_ID ORDER BY list_price DESC) as Rnk
  from
    books BK
    INNER JOIN book_topics BT
      ON BT.book_id = BK.book_ID
)
SELECT topic_id, book_id, list_price
  FROM cteBookCostsPerTopic
  WHERE  Rnk=1-- i.e. most expensive
         and topic_id = 'DB'
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04eaa/1)